# Conditions in shell script not working

Tags: linux, shell, unix

My shell program is:

```
  testname=methun
  echo "Please enter your name:"
  read username
  if [ "$username" == "$testname"]; then
   age=20
   echo " you are $age years old."
  else
    echo "How old are you?"
    read Age
    if [ "$Age" -le 20]; then
      echo "you are too young."
   else
    if["$Age" -ge 100]; then
      echo " You are old."
    else 
      echo "you are young."
  fi  fi fi
```

Now when I run my program, it's able to take user input and it shows an error.
The error is given below:

```
./filename line linenumber:sysntax error near unexpected token 'then'
./filename line linenumber: 'if["$username" -eq "$testname"]; then'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing some whitespaces:

```
#!/bin/bash
testname=methun
echo "Please enter your name:"
read username

if [ "$username" == "$testname" ]; then
  age=20
  echo " you are $age years old."
else
  echo "How old are you?"
  read Age
  if [ "$Age" -le 20 ]; then
    echo "you are too young."
  else
    if [ "$Age" -ge 100 ]; then
      echo " You are old."
    else
      echo "you are young."
    fi
  fi
fi
```

Comment: I rechecked, to be really sure and no, that code does execute without an error.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some spaces inside your brackets.  It needs to be like this:

```
if [ "$username" -eq "$testname" ]; then
```

Then  you will realize you have a second problem, which is `-eq` is for numbers, not strings.  So:

```
if [ "$username" = "$testname" ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a few whitespaces:

```
if [ "$username" == "$testname" ] ; then
                               ^
                               |
                             here
```

Or else the string to compare to will be the value of `$testname` plus an `]`. Then the `]` will be missing and thus a syntax error.

The same is true for every `if` in your script.

The space between `]` and `;` is not strictly needed, but I like it anyway.

Comment: `==` is not POSIX; `=` is.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Good to know, but I doubt this is related to the OP problems.